# "Can I add sugar in/to milk?" Which preposition is correct?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

I want to say "Can I add sugar in/to milk?" Should I use "in" or "to"?

Answer (score 3):

You should use "add to" when the sentence specifies what is receiving the sugar and "add in" (or just "add") when it doesn't. Compare

> I have a glass of milk. Can I add sugar to it?

vs

> I have a glass of milk. Can I add in sugar?

Answer (score 0):

"Can I add sugar to milk?" would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you are holding a mug of milk  and adding sugar to it for taste then you will use the preposition **to**

In this case you might also change the sentence slightly to read:

**Can I add sugar to **my** milk?**

Using the position **to** in this context makes sense because **to** is functioning to show a **transfer** from **person** to **place**. (from you to the mug of milk).  The use of **in or into** would only suggest position and lack the idea of **transfer or movement**.

I hope that helps.

**Some help from: The Ins and Outs of Prepositions By Jean Yates Ph.D.**